# How to call the parent thread function from the separately running child thread in loop in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, qt5

I have the `QMainWindow::show()` and `hide()` functions respectively in the MainWindow class that creates the Qt window (GUI) and returns the `exec()`. From the same class constructor, I have called made the thread to another class slot function that runs in a background continuously listening to the global mouse coordinates and it should toggle display/hide the GUI mainwindow when the mouse is at the bottom of the screen and is moving along the x axis. Here is the code :

```
#include "mainwindow.hpp"
#include "Xmousetrack.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    MouseTrack * mT = new MouseTrack;
    mT->moveToThread(&mouseThread);

    connect(&mouseThread, SIGNAL(finished()), mT, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signalPointer(int&,int&)), mT, SLOT(trackPointer(int&,int&)));
    mouseThread.start();
}

void MainWindow::showDisplay()
{
    MainWindow::show();
}

void MainWindow::hideDisplay()
{
    MainWindow::hide();
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    mouseThread.requestInterruption();
    mouseThread.quit();
    mouseThread.wait();
}

// class blueprint in Xmousetrack.hpp
MouseTrack::MouseTrack()
{
    dpr = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!dpr)
    {
      std::cerr << "XOpenDisplay(0x0) returned 0x0" << std::endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Xheight = HeightOfScreen(dpr);
    Xheight -= (Xheight - 20); //the last 20 height in pixels of the screen
    xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
}

MouseTrack::~MouseTrack() { xdo_free(xdo); }


void MouseTrack::trackpointer(int &x, int &y) //slot function 
{
    xdo_get_mouse_location(xdo, &x , &y , CURRENTWINDOW); // libx11 fucntion
    prev_x = x;

    while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
    {
        usleep(1000);
        xdo_get_mouse_location(xdo, &x , &y , CURRENTWINDOW);
        if ( abs(x - prev_x) > 10 and y >= Xheight)
        {
            hide = 1 - hide;
            if (hide == 0)
           {
            // I NEED TO CALL MainWindow::showDisplay() here 
           }

        }


    }
}
```

I have tried all the Qt mouse functions for the purpose and failed and now I am using X11 lib and it works fine as a separate module. This is my problem in combined all in one and calling the `MainWindow::showDisplay()` function of the parent thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've set this up, the `MainWindow` and the `MouseTrack` objects live in different threads. So directly calling the `MainWindow::showDisplay()` member function from `MouseTrack::trackpointer()` is not a good idea. This is exactly what signals and slots are for.

Add a signal to your `MouseTrack` class, called something like `requestHide(bool)`, and connect it to the `MainWindow::setVisible()` slot. In the `MouseTrack::trackpointer()` function, emit the signal with `emit requestHide(hide)`. The `MainWindow` will then toggle its visibility.

Comment: Will it stop the child thread being running? If not, then while emitting the signal, will the thread pause inside the block `if (hide == 0)` or will it just emit the signal and the child thread remains in the execution?

Comment: @xcfg96 No, emitting a signal does not block. It will continue with the while-loop until the thread is interrupted. Keep in mind, though, that this will emit a signal *each time* it goes through the loop and the condition is valid. Also, doing `hide = 1 - hide` means that the visibility of the main window will *toggle* each time through the loop if the if-statement condition is met. I think you just want to set `hide` to the value of that if-statement's condition. I.e., hide if the position is something, else show.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing, can you give me a `connect` statement as mine is giving error as I don't know how to create object of MainWindow? I tried but failed in errors : `connect(&mouseThread, SIGNAL(MouseTrack::toggleMainDisplay(bool)), MainWindow, SLOT(MainWindow::changeDisplayStatus(bool)), Qt::DirectConnection);`
I will implement your above comment. I got it. But what about the parent class object inside the connect function?

Comment: That's because the signal is not a member of the thread object, it's a member of the `MouseTrack` object. Make the connection in the `MainWindow` constructor, where you make the others. Use `QObject::connect(mT, &MouseTrack::toggleMainDisplay, this, &MainWindow::changeDisplayStatus)`. I'd really recommend you (re-)read the docs on [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to use `X11`-specific stuff for this. All `QWidget` subclasses (including your `MainWindow`) receive events related to mouse tracking, such as position, clicks, etc. You can override the [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) event handler, doing the hiding/showing of the window within that method. Look at how [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) overrides that event-handler for details.